# Akka Actor "ask" and "Await" with TimeoutException

Tags: scala, actor, akka

I'm modeling a simple P2P with Scala and Akka:

```
class Node() extends Peer with Actor {

  var peers: List[ActorRef] = List()

  def receive = {
    case _register(peer: ActorRef, p: Option[Int]) => {
      println("registering [" + peer + "] for [" + this + "]")
      peers = peer :: peers
    }
  }

}

sealed case class _register(val peer: ActorRef, var p: Option[Int] = None)
```

and then a simple network:

```
class Network() extends Actor {

  def this(name: String) = {

    this()

    val system = ActorSystem(name)

    val s1 = system.actorOf(Props(new Node()), name = "s1")
    val s2 = system.actorOf(Props(new Node()), name = "s2")

    val c1 = system.actorOf(Props(new Node()), name = "c1")
    val c2 = system.actorOf(Props(new Node()), name = "c2")
    val c3 = system.actorOf(Props(new Node()), name = "c3")
    val c4 = system.actorOf(Props(new Node()), name = "c4")

    implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 second)

    s1 ? _register(c1)
    s1 ? _register(c2)
    s1 ? _register(c3)
    val lastRegistered = s2 ? _register(c4)
    Await.ready(lastRegistered, timeout.duration)

    println("initialized nodes")
  }
}
```

The output that I'm getting is *always* like:

```
registering [Actor[akka://p2p/user/c1]] for [nl.cwi.crisp.examples.p2p.scala.Node@14b5f4a]
registering [Actor[akka://p2p/user/c2]] for [nl.cwi.crisp.examples.p2p.scala.Node@14b5f4a]
registering [Actor[akka://p2p/user/c3]] for [nl.cwi.crisp.examples.p2p.scala.Node@14b5f4a]
registering [Actor[akka://p2p/user/c4]] for [nl.cwi.crisp.examples.p2p.scala.Node@13c0b53]
[ERROR] [04/10/2012 22:07:04.34] [main-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-1] [akka://main/user/p2p] error while creating actor
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5000] milliseconds
    at akka.dispatch.DefaultPromise.ready(Future.scala:834)
    at akka.dispatch.DefaultPromise.ready(Future.scala:811)
    at akka.dispatch.Await$.ready(Future.scala:64)
    at nl.cwi.crisp.examples.p2p.scala.Network.<init>(Node.scala:136)
    at nl.cwi.crisp.examples.p2p.scala.Main$$anonfun$11.apply(Node.scala:164)
    at nl.cwi.crisp.examples.p2p.scala.Main$$anonfun$11.apply(Node.scala:164)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:488)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create$1(ActorCell.scala:506)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:591)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:191)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:160)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:505)
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:259)
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:997)
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1495)
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

I have followed the documentation of [Futures](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/futures.html#futures-scala) on Akka reference documentation. Exchanging `Await.ready` with `Await.result` does not have any effect. The log shows that the last registration has been successful.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are waiting for a message to be returned from the Node actor, but the Node actor does not send a message back to the `sender` actorRef, so the Future[Any] created by `s1 ? _register` will never receive a response, so the Future will never be complete.  You could add `sender ! something` from inside the Node `receive` method to send a response, I'm not sure what `something` makes sense in this case.

Comment: Thanks, that was a sloppy mistake! `sender ! None` would work for me.

Answer (score 8):

stew's got it right, but you've got some worrisome code in your network actor:

```
val system = ActorSystem(name)

val s1 = system.actorOf(Props(new Node()), name = "s1")
val s2 = system.actorOf(Props(new Node()), name = "s2")

val c1 = system.actorOf(Props(new Node()), name = "c1")
val c2 = system.actorOf(Props(new Node()), name = "c2")
val c3 = system.actorOf(Props(new Node()), name = "c3")
val c4 = system.actorOf(Props(new Node()), name = "c4")
```

Why are you creating a new ActorSystem, and why are you creating top-level actors inside that actor system?

If you need access to the actor's system, you simple call:

```
context.system
```

And you should avoid creating top-level actors "just because", for the same reason that you shouldn't clutter the root of your file system by placing all your files there.
To create child-actors to Network, just do:

```
context.actorOf(...)
```

Right now you'll have a problem as soon as you create more than one Network-actor in the same system, as it will attempt to create top-level actors of the same name.