# Akka Actor - wait for some time to expect a message, otherwise send a message out

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Is it possible to make an `Actor` wait for X amount of seconds to receive any message, and if a message is received, process it as usual, otherwise send a message to some other `Actor` (pre-determined in the constructor)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you want to wait for **any** message, you simply set a *receiveTimeout*: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#receive-timeout

(The docs is slightly misleading here, you can set the receiveTimeout after every message also)

Answer (score 18):

It's possible, have a look at [Akka Actor "ask" and "Await" with TimeoutException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095927). But keep in mind that blocking inside an actor is a very bad idea since during that time actor can't handle any other messages. Moreover it blocks one Akka processing thread.

A better approach is to send a message (*fire and forget*) and schedule some timeout event using [Akka scheduler](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/scheduler.html). When the response arrives, cancel that event or set some flag so that it won't trigger if the reply actually came on time.

Answer (score 4):

Might be an overkill, but you might check out the [Finite State Machine (FSM)](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html) trait.

```
import akka._
import actor._
import util._
import duration._
import Impatient._

object Impatient {
  sealed trait State
  case object WaitingForMessage extends State
  case object MessageReceived extends State
  case object TimeoutExpired extends State

  sealed trait Data
  case object Unitialized extends Data

  // In
  case object Message
}

class Impatient(receiver: ActorRef) extends Actor with FSM[State, Data] {
  startWith(WaitingForMessage, Unitialized)

  when(WaitingForMessage, stateTimeout = 3 seconds) {
    case Event(StateTimeout, data) => goto(TimeoutExpired) using data // data is usually modified here
    case Event(Message, data) => goto(MessageReceived) using data // data is usually modified here
  }

  onTransition {
    case WaitingForMessage -> MessageReceived => stateData match {
      case data => log.info("Received message: " + data)
    }
    case WaitingForMessage -> TimeoutExpired => receiver ! TimeoutExpired
  }

  when(MessageReceived) {
    case _ => stay
  }

  when(TimeoutExpired) {
    case _ => stay
  }

  initialize
}
```

Here it is in action:

```
object Main extends App {
  import akka._
  import actor._
  import Impatient._

  val system = ActorSystem("System")

  val receiver = system.actorOf(Props(new Actor with ActorLogging {
    def receive = {
      case TimeoutExpired => log.warning("Timeout expired")
    }
  }))

  val impatient = system.actorOf(Props(new Impatient(receiver)), name = "Impatient")
  impatient ! Message

  val impatient2 = system.actorOf(Props(new Impatient(receiver)), name = "Impatient2")
  Thread.sleep(4000)
  impatient2 ! Message

  system.shutdown()
}
```