# AKKA timeout on message

Tags: java, akka

I'm using java with akka. I have this situation:

Actor A sends a message to actor B.

B waits a timeout and, if in this timeout no identical message(same type of message) occours, sends a message to actor C.

How can I implement it? What I have to write in B onReceive method?

```
public void onReceive(Object message){
        if(message instanceof EventOccurred){
             //wait a timeout to see if other EventOccurred message are   coming               
             //and then send a messago to actor C
        }
}
```

In my project I have a file system watcher who receives events when a file is modified,created or deleted (This is actor A), on first I'm watching only a file.

When an event on this file occours my actor A sends a message to another actor(actor B) that first wait a timeout and secondly,if no other events occurred on that file(so if no other message are arrived on actor B), sends a message to actor C that calculate an hash of that file.

@Snickers3192 I implemented all this things I wanted only to know if it's really possible with akka.

Comment: Do you know why you shouldn't use blocking code in an onReceive method?

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean with blocking code in this case? You say that in your vision it's wrong because in this waiting time the actor won't process any other message and so other message will accumulate in mailbox?

Comment: There we go. So what is an alternative?

Comment: I don't know, I studied routers, scheduler but I haven't seen a solution and maybe there isn't because I can't avoid this problem. Maybe akka is not the way to do it. I tried to think other actorsystem structure but nothing helped me. Or maybe the mailbox can be costumed in a better way. I'm aking here because there are people(like you) more experienced than me that can give me some advise. Maybe using other API.

Comment: Look... in B's receive method you could get B to store the last message from A and then schedule a new message for your timeout duration to B. Once that message comes, you check that the last B message is still the same one. If it is, bingo, you send the message to C. And yay your answer. But you should avoid this sort of stuff at all cost. And NEVER put blocking waits in your receive methods.

Comment: It's not really how my system have to work but you gave me a great idea. Storing things in actors was the key. On first message I hated you but now I love you! Thank you!!

Comment: (I'm jocking I didn't hate you)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [ReceiveTimeout](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.13/java/untyped-actors.html#Receive_timeout) can help you.  It's a message driven non-blocking way to receive a timeout. From Akka docs:

> setReceiveTimeout defines the inactivity timeout after which the
>   sending of a ReceiveTimeout message is triggered

```
public class MyReceiveTimeoutUntypedActor extends UntypedActor {

    public MyReceiveTimeoutUntypedActor() {
        // To set an initial delay
        getContext().setReceiveTimeout(Duration.create("30 seconds"));
    }

    public void onReceive(Object message) {
        if (message.equals("Hello")) {
            // To set in a response to a message
            getContext().setReceiveTimeout(Duration.create("1 second"));
        } else if (message instanceof ReceiveTimeout) {
            // To turn it off
            getContext().setReceiveTimeout(Duration.Undefined());
        } else {
           unhandled(message);
        }
    }
}
```

See also:

> if you want to wait for any message, you simply set a receiveTimeout - Viktor Klang
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/12754034/1956540